# Backquote symbol list ending in period

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

I'm curious if there is a way to end a backquoted symbol list with a period following a comma inserted value.

Here is the sample code:

```
(defparameter *things* '(book pencil shoe))
(defun inspect-item (item things)
    (if (member item things)
        `(you pick up the ,item and yeet it out the window.)
        `(only realize the truth... there is no ,item.)))
```

This will succeed `(print (inspect-item 'book *things*))` and it produces the symbol list `(YOU PICK UP THE BOOK AND YEET IT OUT THE WINDOW.)`. I assume in this case that the period is part of the symbol `WINDOW.` (as confirmed using the last function).

However, this will fail `(print (inspect-item 'spoon *things*))` claiming that variable `ITEM.` has no value (Because it thinks the name is `item.`). Leaving a space between item and the period gives the error `illegal end of dotted list` which I assume is because it is assuming I'm using dotted list syntax.

Is there any way to get it to produce the symbol I want at the end (`BOOK.`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible requirements for a solution**

You need to create a new symbol based on an old one:

- the same name, with a `.` appended
- probably in the same package

**Period as a symbol**

Note that you can write a symbol with the period as a name using an escaped symbol: `|.|` or `\.`.

```
CL-USER 17 > (let ((item 'foobar))
               `(only realize the truth... there is no ,item \.))
(ONLY REALIZE THE TRUTH... THERE IS NO FOOBAR \.)
```

`princ` prints without escape characters:

```
CL-USER 18 > (princ '(ONLY REALIZE THE TRUTH... THERE IS NO FOOBAR \.))
(ONLY REALIZE THE TRUTH... THERE IS NO FOOBAR .)       ; <- printed output
(ONLY REALIZE THE TRUTH... THERE IS NO FOOBAR \.)      ; <- REPL value
```

**Solution**

```
CL-USER 19 > (defun add-suffix (symbol suffix)
               (intern (concatenate 'string
                                    (symbol-name symbol)
                                    (symbol-name suffix))
                       (symbol-package symbol)))
ADD-SUFFIX

CL-USER 20 > (let ((item 'tree))
               `(we went to the ,(add-suffix item '|.|)))
(WE WENT TO THE TREE.)
```

It can also be useful to use the flexibility of `format` instead of using `concatenate`.

```
CL-USER 22 > (defun add-suffix (symbol suffix)
               (intern (format nil "~a~a" symbol suffix)
                       (symbol-package symbol)))
ADD-SUFFIX
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the real problem lies in the attempt to produce *text* just as the printed representation of a *list of symbols*.  Those are completely different things.  The only reason to do it like this could be as some kind of exercise.  There are a number of introductory texts that do that kind of thing.

Instead, I'd advise to actually produce text, i. e. strings.  You might use the `format` function that is quite flexible for inserting variable things:

```
(defparameter *things* '("book" "pencil" "shoe"))

(defun inspect-item (item things)
  (if (member item things :test #'string-equal)
      (format nil
              "You pick up the ~a and yeet it out the window."
              item)
      (format nil
              "Only realize the truth… there is no ~a."
              item)))
```

Comment: Oh, certainly. This isn't meant as a correct way of doing things, rather just as a curious exploration of the limits. In any normal situation, you would use strings.

Answer (score 1):

I partly agree with Svante that turning lists of symbols into text is often the wrong thing.  On the other hand things like parsers &c often want to think in terms of symbols rather than strings as symbols have nice properties like `(eq a b)` working the way you would hope.

That being said, here's an alternative approach: create a list of words and then have a function which turns them into a string representing a sentence, adding appropriate punctuation and capitalization.

```
(defparameter *things* '(book pencil shoe))

(defun inspect-item (item things)
  (sentencify (if (member item things)
                  `(you pick up the ,item and yeet it out the window)
                `(only realize the truth... there is no ,item))))

(defun sentencify (slist &key (question nil))
  (format nil "~{~A~^ ~}~A"
          (loop for first = t then nil
                for w in slist
                for ws = (typecase w
                           (symbol (symbol-name w))
                           (string w)
                           (t w))
                collect (typecase ws
                          (string (if first
                                      (string-capitalize ws)
                                    (string-downcase ws)))
                          (t ws)))
          (if question "?" ".")))
```

And now:

```
> (inspect-item 'book *things*)
"You pick up the book and yeet it out the window."

> (inspect-item 'bok *things*)
"Only realize the truth... there is no bok."

> (inspect-item '(x . y) *things*)
"Only realize the truth... there is no (x . y).
```